# Type Assignment in VB.NET on the fly

Tags: vb.net, datatable, types, runtime, variable-assignment

I have a string say, str = "system.Int16"
I want to add a column in DataTable say, dt = new DataTable()
I want DataType for that column as per 'str', i.e. System.Int16
Then How to?
dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn", ...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn", Type.GetType(str, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add the "System.Int16" column by using this code:

str = "system.Int16";
dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn", System.Type.GetType(str));